# How to get Country name by given Postal Code (ZIP) on iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, location, maps

Is it possible to get the country name by giving the postal code of the user?

I looked at the Core Location Framework, but it doesn't look to work the other way around by given the Postal Code and finding the Country name.

> The Core Location framework (CoreLocation.framework) provides location
>   and heading information to apps. For location information, the
>   framework uses the onboard GPS, cell, or Wi-Fi radios to find the
>   user’s current longitude and latitude.

I hope there is a class on iOS SDK, I really don't want to use one of the Google Maps APIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your solution can be found within the iOS SDK.

Hook up a text field to this action:

```
- (IBAction)doSomethingButtonClicked:(id) sender
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:yourZipCodeGoesHereTextField.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        if(error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"error from geocoder is %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
                NSString *city1 = [placemark locality];
                NSLog(@"city is %@",city1);
                NSLog(@"country is %@",[placemark country]);
                // you'll see a whole lotta stuff is available
                // in the placemark object here...
                NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I don't know if iOS supports postal codes for all countries, but it definitely works for the UK (e.g. postal code of "YO258UH") and Canada ("V3H5H1")

Answer (score 2):

[Michael Dautermann's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981049/michael-dautermann) answer is correct, just adding a code for swift (v4.2) if anyone comes to this post looking for it:

```
@IBAction func getLocationTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let zipcode = zipcodeTxtField.text else {
        print("must enter zipcode")
        return
    }

    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(zipcode) { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("Unable to get the location: (\(error))")
        }
        else{
            if let placemarks = placemarks{

                // get coordinates and city
                guard let location = placemarks.first?.location, let city = placemarks.first?.locality else {
                    print("Location not found")
                    return
                }


                print("coordinates: -> \(location.coordinate.latitude) , \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
                print("city: -> \(city)")

                if let country = placemarks.first?.country{
                     print("country: -> \(country)")
                }

                //update UI on main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.countryLbl.text = country
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```